# no se pudo conectar al servidor: conexión rechazada Postgrsql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Me gustaria que me explicasen como puedo resolver este problema 
[image: gra]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el puerto 1234 es el que usa PostgreSQL?

Comment: Estás tratando de conectarte por el puerto 1234, postgres usa el puerto 5432. Es por eso que te rechaza la conexión: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-postgres.html